# How to enrich a command for some parameters only?

Tags: fish

I would like to use the `systemctl` command in a way where

- `systemctl start` (and `stop` and `restart`) also triggers a `systemctl status` for the same service
- all other `systemctl` commands are ran as it
- features such as expansion are retained

I currently have a primitive solution in the form of

```
function sys --wraps systemctl -d "Start service and show its status"
    systemctl restart $argv
    systemctl status $argv
end
```

but not only I usually forget to use it, but it is extremely limited.

I believe that there is first a conditional decision to be made on the first parameter, and then either chain `systemctl <parameter 1> <parameter 2>` or just run `systemctl <parameter 1> ...`

I am stuck at the condition (`if the command is systemctl and first argument is one of ['stop', 'start', 'restart'] then ...`) but also on whether the expansion and memory will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am stuck at the condition (if the command is systemctl and first argument is one of ['stop', 'start', 'restart'] then ...)

That's actually quite simple, in the simple case [1], especially since you *don't* need to check `systemctl` - you want to run `sys start`, not `sys systemctl start`, do you?

So the conditional becomes:

```
if contains -- $argv[1] start stop restart
     systemctl $argv
     systemctl status $argv[2..-1]
else
     systemctl $argv
end
```

which can be simplified as

```
systemctl $argv
if contains -- $argv[1] start stop restart
    systemctl status $argv[2..-1]
end
```

> I would like to use the systemctl command in a way where

This sounds you would like to have a "true" wrapper function, with the same name as the underlying command. That's possible, only it requires specifying `command $thething` every time the underlying command is called.

Also remember that fish functions are usually available even if the shell isn't interactive, so if you have any scripts calling the wrapped thing, they will end up calling the function.

So you do something like

```
# --wraps isn't necessary because the name is the same.
function systemctl
    # without `command`, this will be an infinite loop
    command systemctl $argv
    if contains -- $argv[1] start stop restart
        command systemctl status $argv[2..-1]
    end
end
```

> features such as expansion are retained

You don't need to do anything here, as the expansions happen *before* your function is called.

---

[1]: There is a general problem with options. If you do `systemctl --user start`, the command is `start`, but it's not the first argument! You could skip all arguments starting with `-` for the purpose of determining the command, but there are also options that take arguments (e.g. `systemctl --host status start`). A general solution here is basically impossible, so the best you can do is something like fish's [argparse](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#argparse), which requires adding all options that the tool supports, and then redoes the argument parsing.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, your scripting language is actually quite powerful! The second code answers exactly my need and I am aware of the issues you mention in [1] - in 99.99% of my use cases this will not be an issue as I use a very few variations of the command anyway. Thanks again.